# What is the meaning of the reference to a young contemporary author?

Tags: allusions, portuguese-language, jorge-amado, the-double-death-of-quincas

At the beginning of Jorge Amado's novel [*The Double Death of Quincas Water-Bray*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Two_Deaths_of_Quincas_Wateryell) (*A Morte e a Morte de Quincas Berro d'Água*, 1959), the narrator seems to allude to something a young contemporary author might write (emphasis mine):

> Presenciada, no entanto, por testemunhas idôneas, largamente falada nas ladeiras e becos escusos, a frase final repetida de boca em boca representou, na opinião daquela gente, mais que uma simples despedida do mundo, um testemunho profético, mensagem de profundo conteúdo (**como escreveria um jovem autor de nosso tempo**).

This can be roughly translated as follows:

> Spoken in the presence of credible witnesses, many times repeated on the hillsides and in hidden alleys, transmitted by word of mouth, his last words represented, in people's opinion, not just a simple farewell from the world but a prophetic testimonial, a message with a profound meaning (as a young contemporary author might write).

(I have no access to an English translation, so I am reading a German one.)

Could the narrator be referring to a type of formulation that some young Brazilian authors used in the late 1950s? If yes, which words actually make up the allusion? Just the words "mensagem de profundo conteúdo" or a larger part of the sentence?